# How to animate a left sidebar as similar to flipkart in ios?

Tags: ios, animation

i had tried to animate left sidebar in ios as in the following link
http://www.appdesignvault.com/custom-transition-slide-out-navigation/
And i got output as below
[image]

But i need an output transition like below as similar to flipkart
[image]

How to make slanting right view controller in swift? Thanks in advance for any help.

@Ashraf, Currently i had used the below code as per your guidelines.

```
  func presentNavigation(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
            let container = transitionContext.containerView()
            let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)
            let fromView = fromViewController!.view
            let toViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)
            let toView = toViewController!.view

            let size = toView.frame.size
            var offSetTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(size.width - 120, 0)
            offSetTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(offSetTransform, 0.6, 0.6)

            snapshot = fromView.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(true)

            container.addSubview(toView)
            container.addSubview(snapshot)

            let duration = self.transitionDuration(transitionContext)

            UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: nil, animations: {

                self.snapshot.transform = offSetTransform

                }, completion: { finished in

                    transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
            })

        }

        func dismissNavigation(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

            let container = transitionContext.containerView()
            let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)
            let fromView = fromViewController!.view
            let toViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)
            let toView = toViewController!.view

            let duration = self.transitionDuration(transitionContext)

            UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: nil, animations: {

                self.snapshot.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

                }, completion: { finished in
                    transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
                    self.snapshot.removeFromSuperview()
            })
        }

@ Ashraf I had tried code as follows

    func degreesToRadians(floatValue: Float) -> CGFloat {
            return CGFloat(floatValue) * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0
    }


    func presentNavigation(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let container = transitionContext.containerView()
        let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)
        let fromView = fromViewController!.view
        let toViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)
        let toView = toViewController!.view

        let size = toView.frame.size
        var offSetTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(size.width - 120, 0)
        offSetTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(offSetTransform, 0.6, 0.6)

        snapshot = fromView.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(true)

        container.addSubview(toView)
        container.addSubview(snapshot)

        let duration = self.transitionDuration(transitionContext)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: nil, animations: {

//            self.snapshot.transform = offSetTransform

            var t: CATransform3D = CATransform3DIdentity
            t.m34 = 1.0 / 500.0
            var floatValue: CGFloat = self.degreesToRadians(60.0)
            t = CATransform3DRotate(t, floatValue, 0, 1, 0)
            self.snapshot.transform = t;

            }, completion: { finished in

                transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        })

    }
```

And am receiving error as "Cannot assign a value of type 'CAtransform3D' to a value of type 'CGAffineTransform'"

Comment: Use CATransform3D with perspective to achieve the effect as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this third party controller , which gives same output as flipkart side menu [link](https://github.com/pixyzehn/AirbnbViewController)

Comment: Thanks, i will try and come back

Answer (score 1):

Use CATransform 3D. Try something more like this:

```
#define degToRad(radians) ((radians) * (180.0 / M_PI))

CATransform3D t = CATransform3DIdentity;
t.m34 = 1.0 / 500.0;
t = CATransform3DRotate(t, degToRad(60.0), 0, 1, 0);
yourLayer.transform = t;
```

Comment: Thanks,  Its giving "Use of unresolved identifier degToRad". How to fix?

Comment: I am way sorry. Forgot to add the degToRad.

Comment: Because you need to add it to the layer of your view controller.

Comment: Thanks, had choose third party library mentioned by @Tejas. Thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 1):

you should use this api which have same animation like flipkart app

https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu

Comment: Thanks, i will try and come back